# To what object does $this refers when it is used in laravel blade templates?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-jetstream

In jetstream profile managing scaffolding in @if statements $this->enabled is used. And I can't understand to what particular object does it refers?

The file I am looking at "resources\views\profile\two-factor-authentication-form.blade.php":

```
            @if ($this->enabled)
                {{ __('You have enabled two factor authentication.') }}
            @else
                {{ __('You have not enabled two factor authentication.') }}
            @endif
```

Stackoverflow system does not allow me to include the whole file so I hope that the part of code I have included is enough.

Comment: If you do `dd($this);`, you should be able to see what class it is.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson thank you for your answer, should I delete this question, or it can be useful for the community?